# Add login screen infront of TabBar in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an application containing a tab bar view and I have a login xib(login.xib) and its corresponding class files(LoginController) in the same application. I want that when my application launches, the login file should be loaded first and then once I click on the login button, my TabBar View should be launched.

Tried a lot many ways, but nothing worked. :(

Latest one is I tried putting the following code in the AppDelegate file at the end of application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but facing an error:

```
loginController = [[LoginController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];
[window addSubview:loginController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Error is "loginController" is undeclared.

Am I missing something. Please let me know if there are any other ways through which I can fulfill my requirement.

Also, on clickButton() inside the login, I am using event Touch Up Inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
loginController = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"login" bundle:nil];
[window addSubview:loginController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Add following line when you have finished your login checks.

```
[window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];
```

Also, please check where the loginCont is used?

Thanks,

Comment: Ok am trying this out... but one more query. Whats "initWithNibName:@"login"" ?? What does login stand for in this?

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Do I need to declare anything in .h file?? loginCont is nothing but loginController... I had renamed it.

Comment: yes login is your your .xib name(as you mentioned). just add #import "LoginController.h" in header.... it will work..... thanks

Comment: I am still getting the error after adding the header file in the AppDelegate... no idea why... :(

Comment: Do we add anything in AppDelegate.h for LoginController?

Comment: have you declared LoginController *loginController in appDelegate

Comment: yes write LoginController *loginController in your appDelegate header

Comment: Hmmm now am getting some more errors for the declaration in header. It says "Expected specifier-qualifier-list" before "LoginController".

Comment: could you please post your appDelegate's .h and .m complete code... so that I can figure it out.

Comment: Added the code above... Please read loginCont as loginController and LoginCont as LoginController...

Comment: Hey Ravin, I am not getting those errors now... But no application is being loaded. But thanks anyways for all the help... :D :D

Comment: remove this line [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
from applicationFinishLaunching and add it in LoginViewController when login successfull you will need to appDelegate object in order to access this tabBarController ............ TabBarAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TabBarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  and then use [window addSubview:appDelegate.tabBarController.view];...... thanks

Comment: have you connected login.xib with LoginViewController..... as its file owner.... ?

Comment: Yeah... my xib name is Login1.xib and my code is               loginCont = [[LoginCont alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login1" bundle:nil];

Comment: please update the above code in post... Also I want to know from which view controller you are using tabBarController..... why dont you just put this tabBarController in that viewController's xib rather than mainWindow.xib......

Comment: Hi Ravin, I tried linking everything again and now I am able to get the login page during the app launch, but not able to get on the tab Bar View when I click on the button at the login form. I am posting the code above.

Comment: I have added the modified AppDelegate code and the login code as well

Comment: -(IBAction)clickedButton:(id)sender{

    TabBarAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TabBarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; [self.view removeFromSuperView];
    [window addSubview:appDelegate.tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}....... try this.

Comment: Ohh you had suggested me before as well... but that didn't work for me... so I removed "TabBarAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TabBarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];"

Comment: Nopes... Tried again and its giving me a hard time

Comment: have you removed [self.view removeFromSuperView]...... In which XIB you are creating tabBarControler outlet(using IB) .. and please recheck the connection tabBarConroller with the outlet variable..

Comment: recently we have solved this problem in this case he has navigationController but presentModalView would me more appropiate since login is temporary task..... here you just need to present LoginViewController(you can add tabBarController at window)......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633074/iphone-login-screen-problem/5633277#5633277

Comment: I think this would be more easy to do.... but still you want to adopt view additing approach we have to check everything.... the tabBarController object ..... try to print tabBarController object..... using NSLog(@"Tab Bar Controller : %@",appDelegate.tabBarViewController) or your own login tabBarcontroller.

Comment: Sorry I am very newbie to Iphone and objective C, so asking a weird doubt. But my understanding is if I use presentModalView for Login then I would be adding the code for it in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" and then add code for tabBarController on window in my LoginController.m file?

Comment: no, then you will have to add tabBarController.view in appDelegate ...- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    loginCont = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:nil];
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginCont animated:NO];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

Comment: Ok... I guess I got the idea... will try it out and let you the know the outcome... :)

Comment: No it didn't work out for me... its directly launching tab bar view... loginCont = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:nil];
 [loginCont.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
 
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
 [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginCont animated:NO];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible]; return YES;

Comment: please try with this....... add tabBarController.view to window after presenting the loginController....

Comment: Nopes not working -  loginCont = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:nil]; [loginCont.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginCont animated:NO]; [window addSubview:tabBarController.view]; [window makeKeyAndVisible]; return YES;

Comment: I think its not presenting the loginController out... I tried commenting then window part i.e. for tabBarController thinking that the login model would get launched, but it didn't.

Comment: I think the problem is with [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginCont animated:NO]; we do not have self.window.rootViewController object. Please NSLog it and see the result.... if it is null than we are missing this thing.

Comment: [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] topViewController] this line of code will give us the viewController associated with first tabBar...... [[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] topViewController]presentModalViewController:loginCont animated:NO];  use this instead of previous..... and also change at time of dismissal......

Comment: Hi... I haven't tried this yet... Will try it and let you know... Thanks :)

Comment: Value for self.window.rootViewController is null... my application doesn't get loaded if I use the "[[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] topViewController]presentModalViewController:loginCont animated:NO];"

Answer (score 2):

Just try using:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{

     UIView *indicatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
     UIImageView *splashV=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
     [splashV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];    
     [indicatorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

     [indicatorView addSubview:splashV];
     [self.window addSubview:indicatorView];

     //Take button check credentials on successful login call  StopViewOnsuccessfullogin

}

-(void)StopViewOnsuccessfullogin
{
    [indicatorView removeFromSuperview];
    [splashV release];
        [window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Hope that will work .....

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to change the view controller property of the AppDelegate in Interface Builder to your new View Controller's XIB file.

Move the Tab Bar & associated view controllers into another nib, and only load that once the login screen is finished.