# iPhone login screen problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I have a large application. It has a lot of tables and navigation between them. I started a project as a 'NavigationBasedProject' (xcode template). But now I need to add login at the start of the application. So here what I did so far:
In 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' I added:

```
loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
        [loginViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
```

When user data are valid I dismiss login screen like this:

```
[self.loginViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

User can also logout from application. And then I present login screen again like this:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
```

And this works. But text fields on login screen are still filled with data that user enter to login. And I am afraid that I have some memory issue here. How to remove login screen completely from memory when user logs in. I don't use GUI designer I connect everything from code.
Also I wonder is it good idea to make login screen and modal view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use....  (I don't know why you are declaring it `loginViewController` at class level)

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
            [loginViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
            [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
    [loginViewController release];
```

and for dismissal .....

```
[self.window.rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Thanks,

Comment: I have to because I have to access that variable from a few methods. I create login view in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' but I dismiss it in another method.

Answer (score 1):

Did u release loginViewcontroller after presenting.

```
loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
        [loginViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
[loginViewController release];
```